# Fisher Information Matrix for sinusoidal signal under multiplicative noise

Tags: signal-detection, statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood-estimation

Consider observations ($y$) of a sinusoidal wave with multiplicative noise ($v$) where we are estimating unknown frequency ($\omega$) and unknown initial phase ($\theta$). We can write this system model for $k^{th}$ observation as
$$
y_k = \sin(k \omega + \theta)\times v_k
$$
where, multiplicative noise ($v$) is normally distributed i.e. $v \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. I know, conditional probability can be written as
$$
p(y_k|\omega,\theta) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sin(k \omega + \theta) \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y_k}{\sigma \sin(k \omega + \theta)}\right)^{2}}.
$$
After ignoring constants, the log-likelihood function for $N$ observations can be written as
$$
L(\omega, \theta;\mathbf{y}) = - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log{\sin(k \omega + \theta)} - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \left(\frac{y_k}{\sin(k \omega + \theta)}\right)^{2}.
$$
I am trying to find Fisher information matrix for this problem ($\mathbf{J}(\omega,\theta)$). Am I on right track? How to solve this after taking the 2nd order derivative and by taking expectation?

Comment: That's an odd noise model since without any noise, the output is just zero. Perhaps you mean $y = sin (k\omega) \cdot (1+ v_k)$? This would mean there is multiplicative noise in addition to a noise free term.   The term $k\omega$ also feels a bit odd since I would interpret this as "the frequency of observation 2 is twice the frequency of observation 1". Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Actually, this problem is a subproblem of my overall system. In the overall system, I have a non-zero term when no noise is available. What I have written is the imaginary part of observation as $y$ and $v$ is the imaginary part of noise which is multiplicative. In short, this seems odd though this is required according to my model. And about your second question, $\omega = 2\pi f T$ is the normalized frequency offset and $\omega$ is constant throughout all observations, just phase changes from observation to observation (due to constant frequency offset).

Comment: Sorry, but your notation makes no sense to me. $y_k = sin(k\omega)$ means that the frequency is a function of $k$, but you are saying it's not. Which one is it? You may have a better chance of getting an answer, if you provide the full model and clean up your notation.

Comment: @Hilmar I have explained in another question (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/75944/57983), please look there. Your response will be highly appreciated. Thanks!